# Coroutine function isn't working as expected in unity. (I am a beginner somewhat)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Ok so I have been trying to write a Coroutine that will wait 2 seconds before the health gets deducted more. No errors show up, but the script doesn't wait 2 seconds. I am a beginner, so I don't know what's going on here that could cause the error. I'm guessing I spelled something incorrectly.
Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Die : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int Health;
    public int GolemDamage;
    public Animator anim;
    public Transform enemy;
    public bool canAttack = true;
    public bool justAttacked = false;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    void Update()
    {
    float distance = Vector3.Distance(enemy.position, transform.position);
    canAttack = true;

    if(canAttack == false)
    {
        GolemDamage = 0;
    }
    if(canAttack == true)
    {
        GolemDamage = 10;
    }
    if(distance <= 2.5f)
    {
            Health = Health - GolemDamage;
            justAttacked = true;
    }
    if(justAttacked == true)
    {
        canAttack = false;
        StartCoroutine("Attack");
    }
    if(justAttacked == false)
    {
        canAttack = true;
    }
    }    

    IEnumerator Attack()
    {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    justAttacked = false;
    StartCoroutine("Attack");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are again starting the coroutine in the coroutine itself:

```
IEnumerator Attack() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    justAttacked = false;
    StartCoroutine("Attack");//here
}
```

Try starting it just where you need it to execute and add some helper logs Like so:

```
if(justAttacked == true) {
    canAttack = false;
    Debug.Log("coroutine started");
    StartCoroutine("Attack");
}

IEnumerator Attack() {
    Debug.Log("log before wait");
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);
    Debug.Log("log after wait");
    justAttacked = false;
    StartCoroutine("Attack");//here
}
```

I the console you can check if the logs make sense so that you can move on. Also you can check if between `Debug.Log("log before wait");` and `Debug.Log("log after wait");` there are 2 seconds, as you can see the time of each log in the console.

Comment: Note you also set justattacked by distance irrelevant of anything else so while distance is close enough you are calling it all again

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that when you call something that doesn't run inside the unity editor like (Admob) this happen to StartCoroutine, the solution is to set
for example:

```
public static void show()
{
    #if !UNITY_EDITOR
    if (interstitial.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitial.Show();
        requist_ad = true;
    }
    else
    {
        requist_ad = true;
    }
    #endif
    //Debug.Log("not mobile");
}
```

I know that it's not the case here but it's for others that came here about the Startcoroutine problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where the Coroutine wouldn't trigger no matter what.

In my case I was calling the Coroutine from a WebSocket thread (websocket-sharp). Apparently Unity is not thread-safe, which means that things don't trigger when they should.

What solved it for me was setting a simple boolean flag on the WebSocket thread and then checking it on the `Update()` function, and if true triggering the Coroutine (and setting it back to false). It isn't that clean, but it definitively worked!